# VueJs splice row with id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to delete my item from database and it is deleting successfully but my item won't splice from list.

> I am aware that i should probably use `index` in order to splice but
>   if i use `index` then i cannot pass my `itemID`in order to send it to
>   back-end so kind of stuck in the situation.

#### Issue

1. If i use `index` it sends index number to back-end which is wrong
2. If i use `itemId` it will delete the item from database but won't be
   removed from list

## code

`HTML`

```
<el-col :span="9" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <template v-for="itemm in item.children" >
        <div :key="itemm.id">
            <!-- child's -->
            <el-input :value="itemm.name" placeholder="Please input your variation value" class="input-with-select">
            <el-button slot="append" @click="removeSavedChild(itemm.id)" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button>
            </el-input>
        </div>
    </template>
</el-col>
```

`Script`

```
data() {
  return {
     savedVariations: [],
  }
},
methods: {
  removeSavedChild(id){
    axios.delete('/api/admin/variations/destroy/'+id).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.success);
        this.savedVariations.splice(id, 1);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
  },
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try filtering the array instead, ie `this.savedVariations = this.savedVariations.filter(sv => sv.id !== id)`

Comment: How is the `item.children` referenced in your template related to `savedVariations`?

Comment: @skirtle it's under another array, but looping is not my issue splice them item is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both id and index for it. Like below

```
removeSavedChild(id, index, items){
    axios.delete('/api/admin/variations/destroy/'+id).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.success);
        items.splice(index, 1);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
  },
```

in your click event you will pass like this.

```
@click="removeSavedChild(itemm.id, index, item.children)"
```

assuming the in your for loop you put index there, like this

```
<template v-for="(itemm, index) in item.children" >
```

Comment: it didn't delete it from view

Comment: but you said at first you use index and it delete in view ? It's just the same

Comment: what can i say?! :) with your code still behaving same as my code, deletes from database but not view

Comment: yes because your removing the item not the children right ?

Comment: would you like i share my app with ngrok so you can test it yourself?

Comment: okay sure. Just check again my answer. I'm sure it already solve your question

Comment: http://ae8e70cc.ngrok.io/dashboard/products/add  (username: admin@admin.com / password: password)

Comment: maybe you could avoid showing url, user and password